# How to make the "nodemon" to watch only single file?

Tags: node.js, nodemon

In my case the output file (`FrontServerEntryPoint.js`) is being built by the Webpack.

```
nodemon LocalDevelopmentBuild/FrontServerEntryPoint.js --environment local
```

I want `nodemon` watch only this file.
I have no the unambiguous experimental results but I suspect that `nodemon` watches all `.js` file because think that all such
files are related with entry point.
If so, please teach me to make the `nodemon` watch only `FrontServerEntryPoint.js`, or suggest the alternative which can do it.

Comment: Use the `-w` argument, `nodemon -w ./file.js file.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some quick experiment, following nodemon config only watches a single file:

```
{
    "restartable": "rs",
    "ignore": [
        ".git",
        "node_modules/**/node_modules"
    ],
    "verbose": true,
    "execMap": {
        "js": "node --harmony"
    },
    "events": {
        "restart": "osascript -e 'display notification \"App restarted due to:\n'$FILENAME'\" with title \"nodemon\"'"
    },
    "watch": [
        "multipart.js" // this is the only file which nodemon is watching and restarts the server
    ],
    "env": {
        "NODE_ENV": "development"
    },
    "ext": "js,json"
}
```

You can place this file in the root folder of your project.

reference: https://github.com/remy/nodemon/blob/master/doc/sample-nodemon.md

test on mac M1